# Show $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can not be uniformly approximated by polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, proof-verification

> If $f(x)=1/(b-x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, then $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can not be uniformly approximated by polynomials.

---

By contradiction: Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, then there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ such that $$|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$$ Now, pick $\epsilon=1$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{b-x}-p(x)\right|&<1\\
\frac{1}{b-x}-1&<p(x)<\frac{1}{b-x}+1\\
\frac{1-b+x}{b-x}&<p(x)<\frac{1+b-x}{b-x}\\
\end{align*}

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $(a,b)$ that converges to $b$, then we have $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1-b+x_n}{b-x_n}\right)<\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}p(x_n)<\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1+b-x_n}{b-x_n}\right)\longrightarrow\infty<p(b)<\infty$$

---

I get stuck at this step, can someone give me a hint to keep going to solve the problem? thanks

Comment: Almost there. From last inequality, drop the upper bound, which is inmaterial to your claim. Show the lower bound gose to $+\infty$, so p(x) is unbound in (a, b). But, each polynomial is bounded in the in (a, b).

Answer (score 3):

The uniform limit of a sequence of bounded functions is itself bounded. Every polynomial is bounded on $(a,b),$ while $1/(b-x)$ is unbounded there. Therefore $1/(b-x)$ is not the uniform of polynomials on $(a,b).$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ can be uniformly approximated by the sequence of polynomials $P_n$.
For every $c>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $\mid f(x)-P_n(x)\mid<c, x\in (a,b)$. This implies that for $n,m>N, \mid P_n(x)-P_m(x)\mid\leq \mid P_n(x)-f(x)\mid+\mid P_m(x)-f(x)\mid<2c$. We deduce that $\mid P_n(x)-P_m(x)\mid< 2c, x\in (a,b)$. This implies that $\mid P_n(x)-P_m(x)\mid\leq 2c, x\in [a,b]$. Hence, $\|P_n-P_m\|\leq 2c$ where $\|\|$ is defined on $C([a,b])$. Since $C([a,b],\|\|)$ is complete, the sequence $P_n$ converges towards $g\in C([a,b])$, we have $g(x)=f(x), x\in (a,b)$ this is impossible since $g$ must be defined on $[a,b]$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow b}f(x)$ does not exist.